# Simple Error in Adding Odd Elements of Array of Numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Extremely simplistic issue here as I'm new; I'm trying to sum all odd values of an array of numbers, but the function I use does not return ... anything. Slightly lost as to the precise error in the code below...

```
function addOdds(numArray) {
  //create sum variable
  let sum = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if(numArray[i] % 2 === 1) {
      sum = sum + numArray[i];
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: What do you pass as a parameter to that function? If you add `addOdds([1,2,3,4,5,6])` it seems to be working fine.

Comment: This code works fine - it returns the sum of the odd numbers **in an array**

Comment: I'm with the other guys... This code runs as expected. It's verbose and old school, but it works.

Comment: Welcome!
Try to mind the indentation and be consistent in coding.
It will help you and anyone looking at your code to have a smoother experience.
And, unless you are a master (and even then) - don't "save" on semicolons = ALWAYS use them.
PS. as others have said: your code works for us - show us what you are sending to the function - the problem probably lies there...

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array, You don't need to use for loop and attempt complex logic on indexes.

You can just use a built-in JS function "forEach()";

```
let sum = 0;
// nums can be any array
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4];

nums.forEach(num => {
    if (num % 2 === 1) {
    sum = sum + num
 }})

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: What's the point of using map if you're not creating or using the mapped array? Why not Array.forEach()?

Comment: @user1599011 Sure you can use `forEach()`. It will work just the same. It depends upon the circumstances. You have to know the difference b/w `map` & `forEach`. `forEach()` behaves as a `pure function` and returns the same array while the `map` returns an entirely new array as result. But in this case that does not matter. You can use `forEach` as well.

Comment: Array.forEach() doesn't return anything; it executes the code in the callback.
Array.map() returns an array, but since that array wouldn't be used, I don't see the point in using map().

Comment: Yeah surely in that case, if you are concerned about the performance, you should use `forEach()` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to sum numbers in an array is by using [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It is much faster than looping, and allows you to use much less code. The following example leaves the sum the same unless an entry is odd, in which case it adds that entry to the sum.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
const sumOdds = arr => arr.reduce((sum,i) => i % 2 === 0 ? sum : sum + i );
console.log(sumOdds(numbers))
```